# How do I split an SQLAlchemy Declarative model into modules?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to define multiple modules that contain SQLAlchemy Declarative classes. I've written a function in each module called `subclass_base()` into which a Base instance of `declarative_base()` is passed after instantiation. The first module's `subclass_base()` call correctly subclasses the Base instance and the subclasses are visible from outside the function. The second module's call finishes without errors but from both within the function and outside of it all of the subclasses are reflected in `Base.__subclasses__` only some of the time. Here is a minimal working example with only 1 class definition in each module:

modela.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
def subclass_base(Base):
    class Roles(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'roles'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(32))
```

modelb.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
def subclass_base(Base):
    class Locations(Base):
         __tablename__ = 'locations'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(64))
```

test.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from modela import subclass_base as amod
from modelb import subclass_base as bmod

def test():
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            Base = declarative_base()

            amod(Base)

            bmod(Base)
            sc = [subclass.__name__ for subclass in Base.__subclasses__()]
            assert(len(sc) == 2)

            print('.', end='')
            count += 1
        except AssertionError:
            print("Failed after {} successful pass(es)".format(count))
            count = 0
```

I suspect this issue is me overlooking a specific issue of the metaclass work that goes on with declarative_base() but I can't seem to figure out what's happening. I'm also wondering if this is an inheritance issue. Is there a different architectural approach that I should take rather than using a function to subclass a single Base class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't define the class inside a function. Just define the `Base` in a single definition module then import that module from the other modules:

db.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker()

def bind_engine(engine):
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Session.configure(bind=engine)
```

modela.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from db import Base

class Roles(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32))
```

modelb.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from db import Base

class Locations(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
```

user_script.py

```
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
 engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pwd@server/database')
 from yourproject.db import bind_engine
 bind_engine(engine)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my particular problem: one of the modules is intended to be packaged for distribution via pip and so the end user cannot be required to edit the module once installed. Since the end user instantiates their own Base, I need to somehow pass it to the module. Even if I forced the user to use the module's Base, that would still prevent a second module from using the base. The goal is to modularize the app into useful components that have dedicated tables in a shared database.

Comment: Why are you using the user's `Base`? You shouldn't. If the user wants, they can create their own `Base`! @DeanStamler

Comment: So that's interesting. Multiple Bases can share a single database? Do they share a session or engine too? Perhaps that's the solution.

Comment: @DeanStamler the user can provide their engine for you to bind on your base. I edited the answer to show this:

Comment: @DeanStamler about sharing sessions, well, it depends on the use case, if your user wants, they can use your sessionmaker, or they can make their own sessions for their purpose

Comment: Beautiful. That nicely handles credentials too, thanks. I'll test it out.

Comment: What then for foreign key relations? These require explicit referencing and that path leads to circular imports.