# How to split SQLAlchemy-related code into modules

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new to Python. I'm creating an API using Flask and SQLAlchemy. I'm looking for suggestions/solutions for splitting up the SQLAlchemy code into modules. I am trying to modularize my code using the following approach:

- `/models` will contain my SQLAlchemy models
- `/methods` will contain various database methods, such as creating, updating, and deleting a user
- `/routes` will contain my Flask route handlers

I referenced this [Stack Overflow question on how to split SQLAlchemy declarative models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106264/how-do-i-split-an-sqlalchemy-declarative-model-into-modules) and it works to an extent. With the file structure shown below, I am successfully able to split up my database-related code into the desired modules.

```
Directories are denoted with a leading '/'

/my_root_directory
|__ main.py                         Imports my Flask app and runs it
|__ /server
    |__ __init__.py                 Imports my Flask app and database modules
    |__ app.py                      Contains my Flask app
    |__ /database
        |__ __init__.py             Imports initialize_database()
        |__ engine.py               Contains SQLAlchemy's create_engine()
        |__ base.py                 Contains SQLAlchemy's declarative_base()
        |__ session.py              Contains SQLAlchemy's scoped_session(sessionmaker())
        |__ initialize_database.py  Contains initialize_database()
        |__ /models
            |__ __init__.py         Imports my SQLAlchemy User model
            |__ user.py             Contains my SQLAlchemy User model
        |__ /methods
            |__ __init__.py         Imports create_user()
            |__ create_user.py      Contains create_user()
    |__ /routes
        |__ __init__.py             Imports my Flask route handler
        |__ /api
            |__ users_router.py     Contains my Flask route handler for /api/v1/users
```

Here is the flow of my application. I execute `main.py` by running `python main.py` in the terminal, which contains the following code:

**main.py**

```py
from server.app import app
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    debug = os.getenv("ENV") == "dev"
    app.run(debug=debug)
```

In `/server/__init__.py`, I execute *(?)* all of my database-related code:

**/server/__init__.py**

```py
from .app import app
from .database import *
```

`/server/database/__init__.py` initializes the database and tests my database methods:

**/server/database/__init__.py**

```py
from .initialize_database import initialize_database
from .methods.create_user import create_user

initialize_database()
print(create_user("jack"))
print(create_user("john"))
```

This successfully creates new users in my database. Here is the code for both functions. And for completeness, I have also provided the code containing `Session` and `User`:

**/server/database/initialize_database.py**

```py
from .engine import engine
from .base import Base
import os


def initialize_database():
    if os.getenv("ENV") == "dev":
        Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

**/server/database/methods/create_user.py**

```py
from ..session import Session
from ..models import User


def create_user(name):
    user = User(twitch_username=name)
    Session.add(user)
    Session.commit()
    return "Created new user"
```

**/server/database/session.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from .engine import engine
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

**/server/database/models/user.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from ..base import Base

# These SQLAlchemy model mixins don't depend on any relative modules
from .mixins import AutoUUIDMixin, TimeStampMixin


class User(Base, AutoUUIDMixin, TimeStampMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    twitch_username = Column("twitch_username", String(50), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, twitch_username):
        self.twitch_username = twitch_username
```

---

However, when I try to import `create_user()` into my route handler by doing:

**/server/routes/api/users_router.py**

```py
from ...database.methods import create_user as CreateUser
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from server.app import app
  File "~/root_dir/server/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import app
  File "~/root_dir/server/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .routes import users_router
  File "~/root_dir/server/routes/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api import users_router
  File "~/root_dir/server/routes/api/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .users_router import users_router
  File "~/root_dir/server/routes/api/users_router.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ...database.methods import create_user as CreateUser
  File "~/root_dir/server/database/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .initialize_database import initialize_database
  File "~/root_dir/server/database/initialize_database.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .engine import engine
  File "~/root_dir/server/database/engine.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 56, in create
    plugins = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

How do I successfully modularize my database-related logic to be used by my Flask application? I'm open to any approaches and solutions, even if it means restructuring my codebase entirely. I don't have the best understanding on Python modules and scripts, so if possible, providing an explanation of why my current file structure isn't working as intended would be very helpful.

---

Here is a list of my dependencies:

```
Python     3.7.4
Anaconda   4.8.3
```

**requirements.txt**

```
click==7.1.1
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
psycopg2==2.8.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
python-dotenv==0.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.15
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

**environment.yml**

```yaml
name: flask-server
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2020.1.1=0
  - libcxx=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libcxxabi=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libedit=3.1.20181209=hb402a30_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - ncurses=6.2=h0a44026_0
  - openssl=1.1.1f=h1de35cc_0
  - pip=20.0.2=py37_1
  - python=3.7.6=h359304d_2
  - readline=7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - setuptools=46.1.3=py37_0
  - sqlite=3.31.1=ha441bb4_0
  - tk=8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - wheel=0.34.2=py37_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - zlib=1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
  - pip:
    - click==7.1.1
    - flask==1.1.2
    - flask-sqlalchemy==2.4.1
    - gunicorn==20.0.4
    - itsdangerous==1.1.0
    - jinja2==2.11.1
    - markupsafe==1.1.1
    - psycopg2==2.8.5
    - psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
    - python-dotenv==0.12.0
    - sqlalchemy==1.3.15
    - werkzeug==1.0.1
```

---

**EDIT:** Here is the code in `engine.py`.

**/server/database/engine.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os

print(os.getenv(“DATABASE_URL”))
# Sometimes prints None and other times prints “postgresql://localhost:5432/<my-db>“

engine = create_engine(os.getenv(“DATABASE_URL”))
```

Comment: You provided good bit of details, but not quite enough: what's in engine.py. Specifically, line 3 (which has the error): engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")). Is the env variable defined? Can you print() it before this line and tell us what the value is, removing any sensitive info?

Comment: @retd111, I added my code for `engine.py` and the print statement. I don’t think the engine is the problem since I can execute my code successfully when I don’t import `create_user()` into `/server/routes/api/users_router.py`.

Comment: @retd111, after some more fiddling with my application, I think you're right. `DATABASE_URL` was `None`, which is weird because it was printing the url during some runs and `None` during other runs. I flipped the order of my code execution. I first execute my database logic then my Flask application. I also added `load_dotenv()` inside of `engine.py`. I'm not sure if that's needed or recommended but it seems to break without it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get my file structure working after flipping the execution of code. Instead of creating my Flask application first, I execute my database logic.

**/server/__init__.py**

```py
from .app import app
from .database import *
```

becomes

```py
from .database import *
from .app import app
```

I also added `load_dotenv()` inside of `engine.py`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

print(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
# Prints “postgresql://localhost:5432/<my-db>“

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
```